# Remote X Login Linux

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I have got the following problem to solve:

I am working in a school, and there are 30 PCs per room. One for the teacher, 29 for the students. The Students have their own Accounts to work with, but every second week, they are supposed to write a test on a Computer. There are special test-Accounts, which make any communication nearly impossible. The Problem: The Students should not know the password, so the teacher has to go to every pc in order to log in. I can access all the PCs via ssh (without password). Is there some possibility to write a script, which logs all the pcs on? Logging of is simple:

```
for IP in $IPLIST; do
    ssh teacher@$IP 'killall -u testaccount001'
done
```

Now I am searching for a similar script in order to login.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Made a minor mistage, the username isn't the same for all the computers.

ssh teacher@$IP "killall -u $( cat ~/userIPtab/$IP )"

Answer (score 0):

i added an answer because i wanted to use extended formatting, these are questions, and tips ;)

they should not know the password because by using it they can log into other students machines? if true, than just prevent communication with that user

- prevent communication with the given user using iptables:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner testaccount001 -j DROP`

- or prevent other ssh servers from accepting the login,

add to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match User testaccount001
      PasswordAuthentication no
```

or disable `PasswordAuthentication` globally in `sshd`

either way the password for the account can be public

Comment: They shouldn't know the password, because I don't want them to login when there is no exam. I crippled nearly anything, so they even do not know, under which account they are working. This is just another security-issue.

Just in case I missed something, they don't have the opportunity to explore the exam-accounts for security problems. If they get the passwords they can log in while neither me nor anyone else is looking at the pcs.

Comment: you can lock/unlock the accounts for the specific user using `usermod -L`